# Strange compiler error

Tags: c#

quick question really: I have this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Hovel {
    public abstract class DamageType {
        public string GetKillString(string instigatorName, string victimName) {
            return killString.Replace("<inst>", instigatorName).Replace("<vict>", victimName);
        }
        protected string killString = "ERROR_NO_KILLSTRING_DEFINED";

        public string GetDamageString(string instigatorName, string victimName) {
            return damageString.Replace("<inst>", instigatorName).Replace("<vict>", victimName);
        }
        protected string damageString = "ERROR_NO_DAMAGESTRING_DEFINED";
    }

    public class DamageType_Default : DamageType {  
        killString = "ERROR_DEFAULT_DAMAGE_TYPE";
        damageString = "ERROR_DEFAULT_DAMAGE_TYPE";
    }
}
```

To me, that looks fine, but I get this error for the only two lines in DamageType_Default:

```
Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

So... What the?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the following lines

```
killString = "ERROR_DEFAULT_DAMAGE_TYPE";
damageString = "ERROR_DEFAULT_DAMAGE_TYPE";
```

These lines occur inside a class definition at the scope reserved for members definitions but are instead normal code statements.  You'll need to put these in a method (perhaps a constructor)

```
public DamageType_Default : DamageType {
  public DamageType_Default() { 
    killString = "ERROR_DEFAULT_DAMAGE_TYPE";
    damageString = "ERROR_DEFAULT_DAMAGE_TYPE";
  }
}
```

Comment: @Motig or just drink more redbull :)

Answer (score 2):

You're defining a class `DamageType_Default` but you're just putting some code inside it, instead of inside a constructor.  I think you meant:

```
public class DamageType_Default : DamageType {  
  public DamageType_Default() : base() {
    killString = "ERROR_DEFAULT_DAMAGE_TYPE";
    damageString = "ERROR_DEFAULT_DAMAGE_TYPE";
  }
}
```

which will define a constructor in the base class, and the constructor will set those values to the new overridden ones after constructing the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a constructor. Specifically, those two lines of code should be in a constructor.